# Populate django form using dropdown menu for two fields

Tags: django, forms, drop-down-menu

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class DataForm(forms.Form):
    ins = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    contest = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages 
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
import mylife
import codechef
from codechef.models import chef, aprilcook
from forms import DataForm

def all_users(request):
    return render_to_response('C:/Users/shubham/Desktop/code_chef/project/mylife/codechef/templates/allusers.html', { 'user_list': chef.objects.all() })

def print_table(request):
    return render_to_response('C:/Users/shubham/Desktop/code_chef/project/mylife/codechef/templates/tables.html')


def display(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print '-----------------------------------'
            print form
            print '-----------------------------------'
            insti = form['ins'].value()
            return render_to_response('C:/Users/shubham/Desktop/code_chef/project/mylife/codechef/templates/allusers.html', { 'user_list': chef.objects.filter(inst = insti) })
    else:
        form = DataForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'forms.html', {
        'form': form,
    })

def enter_data(request):
    form = DataForm(request.POST)
    return render(request, 'forms.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

forms.html

```
<form action="/display/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_ins">select Institute Name</label>
    <select id="id_ins" class="form-control" size="1">
        <option>select Institute</option>
        <option value="National Institute of Technology, Kurukshetra">National Institute of Technology, Kurukshetra</option>
        <option value="Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, New Delhi">Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, New Delhi</option>
        <option value="Maulana Azad National Institute of Technology, Bhopal">Maulana Azad National Institute of Technology, Bhopal</option>
        <option value="Birla Institute of Technology Mesra">Birla Institute of Technology Mesra</option>
        <option value="Delhi Technological University">Delhi Technological University</option>
        <option value="Shiraz University">Shiraz University</option>
        <option value="Indian Institute of Information Technology, Allahabad">Indian Institute of Information Technology, Allahabad</option>
        <option value="Indian Institute of Technology Guwahati">Indian Institute of Technology Guwahati</option>
        <option value="National Institute of Technology, Kurukshetra">National Institute of Technology, Kurukshetra</option>
        <option value="National Institute of Technology Tiruchirappalli">National Institute of Technology Tiruchirappalli</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="id_contest">select contest Name</label>
    <select id="disabledSelect" class="form-control">
        <option>select Contest</option>
        <option value="JULY LONG">JULY LONG</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox">Agree terms
    </label>
</div>

<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

There are two fields in forms.py : ins and contest, both of which I wish to enter through dropdown menu in the html page. Now the problem lies in the forms.html. I am not able to  populate form fields using dropdown menu. When I use {{ form.ins }} and {{ form.contest }} it works(Data entered manually in textbox is received and correct page is redirected to), but it takes input in the form of textbox. **I am not able to link dropdown menu with my django form**. If I give {{ form.ins }} along with dropdown menu in forms.html then there appears both textbox input and dropdown menu of which only textbox functions properly, there remains no use of dropdown. I wish to recieve form input through dropdown menu and there should be no textbox input in hmtl page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your Form use a form.ChoiceField instead of a CharField().

```
from django import forms

INS_CHOICES = (
    ('NIT', 'Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, New Delhi'),
    ('NSIT', 'Netaji Subhas Institute of Technology, New Delhi'),
    ...
)

class DataForm(forms.Form):
    ins = forms.ChoiceField(choices=INS_CHOICES)
```

For more informations have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield

However you should consider to use a CreateView anyway, because it would be a lot less work:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/